# C - Is this the right way to use strtok in the following situation

Tags: c, strtok

If i have a string that contains 10X15. And i want to separate the 10 and 15. Would the following code be correct. I am concerned about the second part of the code, is putting "NULL" there the right thing to do.

```
char * stringSixrows = strtok(stringSix[0], "X");
char * stringSixcollumns = strtok(NULL, "NULL");
```

//I put the second null there cause its the end of string, im not sure if its right though.

Comment: Why are you passing `"NULL"` as the second argument? Why not `"X"`? It should do the right thing according to the `strtok` documentation.

Comment: To the extent that it is correct to use `strtok()` at all, and given that the data doesn't actually contain any of the letters `N`, `U` or `L` (there is no virtue in repeating the `L`), then it will work.  It is not the normal way to do it.  You'd probably use the empty string `""` in the second call.  You might also consider not using `strtok()` at all (I wouldn't); it would work fine with `char *s6rows = stringSix[0]; char *s6cols = strchr(stringSix[0], 'X'); if (s6cols != 0) *s6cols++ = '\0';` (using a contraction for the local variable names).

Answer (score 1):

I'd say the "canonical" way to obtain the "pointer to the remaining string" is:

```
strtok(NULL, "")
```

`strtok` searches for *any* of the delimiters in the provided string, so if you don't provide any delimiters, it cannot find anything and thus only stops at the end of the input string.

Answer (score 0):

example

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void){
    char stringSix[] = "10X15";
    char *stringSixrows = strtok(stringSix, "X");
    char *stringSixcolumns = strtok(NULL, "X");

    printf("%s, %s\n", stringSixrows, stringSixcolumns);

    return 0;
}
```

---

another way

```
char stringSix[] = "10X15";
char stringSixrows[3];
char stringSixcolumns[3];
char *p;

if(NULL!=(p = strchr(stringSix, 'X')))
    *p = '\0';
else {
    printf("invalid format\n");
    return -1;
}
strcpy(stringSixrows, stringSix);
strcpy(stringSixcolumns, p+1);

printf("%s, %s\n", stringSixrows, stringSixcolumns);
```

---

```
const char *stringSix = "10X15";
int stringSixrows;
int stringSixcolumns;

if(2==sscanf(stringSix, "%dX%d", &stringSixrows, &stringSixcolumns))
    printf("%d, %d\n", stringSixrows, stringSixcolumns);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use strtol to convert the string to numbers as well as seek to the next string. Below code safely does the intended operation:

```
    char stringSix[] = "10X15";
    char * pEnd;
    long firstNumber = strtol (stringSix,&pEnd, 10);
    pEnd = strtok(pEnd, "");
    long secondNumber = strtol (pEnd,&pEnd, 10);
```